# Listitems are acting really weird

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, listitem

I have a website, http://www.veluwenkamp.nl
On the home page at the bottom, you can find 4 listitems (pictures)
They don't align very well, it has to be in one horizontal line.

I tried everything, but I can't make it work.
Can you guys give me some advice?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by adding a `clear: both` to your `ul`

```
.lijstul {
    clear: both;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`

```
.lijstul li{display:inline-block}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VEHaX/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before the list.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div><ul class="lijstul">
<li class="lijstil">
<div class="portfolio-blockimg3">
<div class="portfolio-imgbox3"><img class="boximg-pad" src="http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/wp-content/themes/veluwenk/timthumb.php?src=http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/vknieuw3/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/picisto-20121022090807-597254.jpg&amp;h=86&amp;w=196&amp;zc=1" alt=""></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="lijstil">
<div class="portfolio-blockimg3">
<div class="portfolio-imgbox3"><img class="boximg-pad" src="http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/wp-content/themes/veluwenk/timthumb.php?src=http://veluwenkamp.nl/afbeeldingen/IMG_1359.jpg&amp;h=86&amp;w=196&amp;zc=1" alt=""></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="lijstil">
<div class="portfolio-blockimg3">
<div class="portfolio-imgbox3"><img class="boximg-pad" src="http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/wp-content/themes/veluwenk/timthumb.php?src=http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/vknieuw3/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/sgfw-30.jpg&amp;h=86&amp;w=196&amp;zc=1" alt=""></div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="lijstil">
<div class="portfolio-blockimg3">
<div class="portfolio-imgbox3"><img class="boximg-pad" src="http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/wp-content/themes/veluwenk/timthumb.php?src=http://www.veluwenkamp.nl/vknieuw3/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/20090619_3844_6.jpg&amp;h=86&amp;w=196&amp;zc=1" alt=""></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And you will get the alignment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.lijstul {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put clear:both to the ul class .lijstul and try